# Scala/Spark App with "No TypeTag available" Error in "def main" style App

Tags: scala, types, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm new to Scala/Spark stack and I'm trying to figure out how to test my basic skills using SparkSql to "map" RDDs in TempTables and viceversa.

I have 2 distinct .scala files with the same code: a simple object (with def main...) and an object extending App.

In the simple object one I get an error due to "No TypeTag available" connected to my case class Log:

```
object counter {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
.
.
.
   val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
   import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
   case class Log(visitatore: String, data: java.util.Date, pagina: String, count: Int)
   val log = triple.map(p => Log(p._1,p._2,p._3,p._4))
   log.registerTempTable("logs")
   val logSessioni= sqlContext.sql("SELECT visitor, data, pagina, count FROM logs")
   logSessioni.foreach(println)
}
```

The error at line: `log.registerTempTable("logs")` says "No TypeTag available for Log".

In the other file (object extends App) all works fine:

```
object counterApp extends App {
.
.
.
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
    import sqlContext.createSchemaRDD
    case class Log(visitatore: String, data: java.util.Date, pagina: String, count: Int)
    val log = triple.map(p => Log(p._1,p._2,p._3,p._4))
    log.registerTempTable("logs")
    val logSessioni= sqlContext.sql("SELECT visitor, data, pagina, count from logs")
    logSessioni.foreach(println)
}
```

Since I've just started, I'm not getting two main points:
1) Why does the same code work fine in the second file (object extend App) while in the first one (simple object) I get the error?

2) (and most important) What should I do in my code (simple object file) to fix this error in order to deal with case class and TypeTag (which I barely know)?

Every answer, code examples will be much appreciated!

Thanks in advance

FF

Answer (score 69, accepted):

**TL;DR;**

Just move your case class out of the method definition

The problem is that your `case class Log` is defined inside of the method that it is being used. So, simply move your case class definition outside of the method and it will work. I will have to take a look at how this compiles down, but my guess is that this is more of a chicken-egg problem. The `TypeTag` (used for reflection) is not able to be implicitly defined as it has not been fully defined at that point. [Here are](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19507760/typetags-not-working-inside-of-code-block-scope) two [SO questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18866866/why-there-is-no-typetag-available-in-nested-instantiations-when-interpreted-by) with the same problem that exhibit that Spark would need to use a `WeakTypeTag`. And, [here is the JIRA](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-6649) explaining this more officially