# Spark/SQL: .toDF() error at compile time but not recognized by IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea, apache-spark, dataframe, case-class

I'm getting an error only when I run my project instead of getting it even in the IDE (IntelliJ) with Spark 1.3.0

My Object contains just a single method which gives me this error while running using .toDF() method.
The logic is pretty simple: I load a text file in a RDD and then, using a case class as suggested, I want to map it as TempTable.

I've already used numerous times both .toDF and case classes in order to use SparkSQL as suggested by the [Spark SQL guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html) and I've never seen this error (which is not even recognized as a syntax error by the IDE):

[image]

Here is my code (note that there is no syntax error):

[image]

Can anyone help me finding a solution to this strange behaviour?
Never happened anything like this before.
The only "strange" thing that comes to my mind is that I'm writing code inside a method and not inside the main object.

Thanks in advance!

FF

Comment: what version of spark are you using?*

Comment: wise question: 1.3... I should improve my question adding this detail

Comment: Log is a simple case class (just one attribute) in order to "map" my DF (former RDD) and then register a tempTable as suggested by the Spark SQL documentation.
I'd like to point out that I've already used case class and DF for Spark SQL without problems... the only difference I've noticed, as I've said, is that this time all my code is INSIDE a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I'm trying out your code, I only get one error

`No TypeTag available for Log`.

This can be solved by moving Log outside the method, ideally outside the object as well.

One more thing, don't call the object SparkContext, this will only lead to confusion.

Comment: Thank Marius for the hint about the name of the object; I didn't realize it... anyway... I'll try to move LOG outside but I'm still concerned about this error   which appears just at compile time...

Comment: I've just moved my case class outside the method as you suggested and all seems to work fine... funny thing is that I do not get the error you posted...
In addition, I had the same error (No TypeTag available for CaseClass) in another example and the solution was the same (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143756/scala-spark-app-with-no-typetag-available-error-in-def-main-style-app)... this is a quite strange behaviour by IntelliJ

Comment: IntelliJ doesn't have a full-fledged compiler, that would take too long. When in doubt, compile with scalac / sbt.

Comment: thanks Marius, I'll keep it in mind... hoping this question/answer thread will be helpfull for others, I'm going to edit the title in order to make it clear it's about IntelliJ