# SPARK/SQL:spark can't resolve symbol toDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In my project, my external library is `spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0`, if I press '.', the IDE inform me `toDF()`, but it inform me that can't resolve symbol `toDF()` when I code it in. I'm sorry I can't find the `toDF()` in Apache Spark doc.

```
case class Feature(name:String, value:Double, time:String, period:String)
val RESRDD = RDD.map(tuple => {
    var bson=new BasicBSONObject();
    bson.put("name",name);
    bson.put("value",value);
    (null,bson);
})

RESRDD
 .map(_._2)
 .map(f => Feature(f.get("name").toString, f.get("value").toString.toDouble))
 .toDF()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @yeyimilk. Please be sure to read
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Code you've provided is not reproducible, lacks example input, contains syntactic errors and irrelevant transformations, is poorly formatted and improperly tagged (how is it connect to MySql? Maybe MongoDB, but BSON part is rather loosely related to the rest of the code). Please fix this problems, otherwise you can expect down-votes and close votes.

Comment: I am sorry that I did not express clearly. I used BSON just for explain the type of RESRDD, for saving it to MongoDB. And in my project I should save it to Mysql, too.

Comment: My point is it is always a good idea to reduce the problem to the bare minimum. Something like `sc.parallelize(List(Feature("a", 1.0, "a", "a"))).toDF` should be enough to reproduce the problem. Anyway, I hope you find my answer useful and don't find my comments to harsh.

Comment: Hi, I created a new project and use the guild example of Apache-Spark and when I compile it, it says that NoTagType for Person.

Comment: If it is not directly related to this problem please post it as a separate question.

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry I didn't the regulations last time.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

To be able to to use `toDF` you have to import `sqlContext.implicits` first:

```
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._

case class Foobar(foo: String, bar: Integer)

val foobarRdd = sc.parallelize(("foo", 1) :: ("bar", 2) :: ("baz", -1) :: Nil).
    map { case (foo, bar) => Foobar(foo, bar) } 

val foobarDf = foobarRdd.toDF
foobarDf.limit(1).show
```

Comment: Or avoid the import and just use `sqlContext.createDataFrame(myRDD)`

Comment: Thanks for your help. I try your case but it remains the same. import sqlContext.implicits._  is unused import statement and toDF is also can't  be resolved. So, it may be another false. My project used spark-asssembly-1.2.1 before and I deleted it and imported spark-assembly-1.3.1 last night.

Comment: Thanks, I get the solution. We should let `case class` out of the function, too. Here is the solution [No TypeTage Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143756/scala-spark-app-with-no-typetag-available-error-in-def-main-style-app)

Answer (score 1):

This is a very late response to the question but just for the sake of people who are still looking for the answer:

**Try the same command on Spark 1.6 it will work.**

I was facing the same issue and searched in google  and didn't get solution and then I upgraded Spark from 1.5 to 1.6 and it worked.

If you don't know your Spark version:

```
spark-submit --version (from command prompt)
sc.version (from Scala Shell)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can import `sqlContext.implicits` as followings:

```scala
    val spark = SparkSession.builder().getOrCreate()
    val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
    import sqlContext.implicits._
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**