# How to run MLlib usage examples with Intellij IDE?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

I'm an absolute beginner with Scala, I want to test the Machine Learning library of Spark MLlib on some very simple examples.

I took the first example of the MLlib Main Guide ["Basic Statistics"](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-statistics.html)  and I tried to reproduce it with a worksheet using IntelliJ IDEA, initialised exactly as the [SCALA documentation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/getting-started-intellij-track/getting-started-with-scala-in-intellij.html) describes and having imported correctly all libraries dependencies.

So here is the code:

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.{Matrix, Vectors}
import org.apache.spark.ml.stat.Correlation
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row

val data = Seq(
  Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 1.0), (3, -2.0))),
  Vectors.dense(4.0, 5.0, 0.0, 3.0),
  Vectors.dense(6.0, 7.0, 0.0, 8.0),
  Vectors.sparse(4, Seq((0, 9.0), (3, 1.0)))
)

val df = data.map(Tuple1.apply).toDF("features")
val Row(coeff1: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, "features").head
println(s"Pearson correlation matrix:\n $coeff1")

val Row(coeff2: Matrix) = Correlation.corr(df, "features", "spearman").head
println(s"Spearman correlation matrix:\n $coeff2")
```

The problem arises with toDF: IntelliJ cannot resolve this symbol, thus it cannot create the Dataframe.
I would like to know exactly how to fix this problem. I tried to use

```
val sqlContext= new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
import sqlContext.implicits._
```

like described in [SPARK/SQL:spark can't resolve symbol toDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31143840/spark-sqlspark-cant-resolve-symbol-todf) but it did not work.
The exact solution would be very much appreciated to continue learning and trying the next examples of the MLlib guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out that I had to initialise properly the Spark Session. Here is the code to add.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder()
  .appName("Basic statistics")
  .config("spark.master", "local")
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
```