# Spark UDF error no TypeTag available for string

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to creating a User defined function but when I compile using Eclipse and Maven I get error ***No TypeTag available for String
spark.udf.register("checkBlankorNulls_udf", checkBlankorNulls(_:String,_:String):String)***

Running this code in spark-shell does not produce any errors. But building a JAR throws an error.

```
val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("raw").config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir","C:\\tmp\spark-warehouse").getOrCreate()   

import spark.implicits._ 
   // user defined function to check null or blank values
    def checkBlankorNulls(colName:String, colValue:String):String = {     
           if (colValue== null|| colValue=="null" || colValue ==" ")   
           {
             throw new Exception(colName.concat(" field is null or empty. Partitioned fields cannot be null"))
           }
           else {
             colValue                          
           }                        
    }  
spark.udf.register("checkBlankorNulls_udf", checkBlankorNulls(_:String,_:String):String)
```

Comment: Did you try to define your UDF out of the method definition? Like suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29143756/scala-spark-app-with-no-typetag-available-error-in-def-main-style-app

Comment: I created a new Scala object called "userDefinedFunction" to define my UDF out of the method's definition and now calling it from the main method as spark.udf.register("checkBlankorNulls_udf", userDefinedFunction.checkBlankorNulls_udf(_:String,_:String)) but it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: I am also getting a warning .. materializing requested reflect.runtime.universe.type.TypeTag[String] using package.this.materializeTypeTag[String]  (scala.reflect.runtime.package.universe)

Comment: I have noticed that if I change the input variable type from String to Double it works. But it has to be String. Not sure why it is not able to recognize TypeTag for String Data type